# Can environment variables in Doxygen be expanded when they are arguments to commands?

Tags: doxygen

I am using Doxygen (version 1.8.8) and am having a problem expanding an environment variable within a section command.

The syntax for the section command in Doxygen is given as:

```
\section <section-name> (section title)
```

I would like to expand an environment variable as part of the section title.  That is:

```
\section MY_SECTION $(MY_ENV_VARIABLE)
```

However, in the generated HTML documentation, `$(MY_ENV_VARIABLE)` has not be expanded.  If I put `$(MY_ENV_VARIABLE)` in a paragraph, it does expand correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\section commands are limited in what commands are supported as part of their argument.

It makes sense to support environment variable expansion though, so feel free to file an enhancement request for this here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen

Comment: Thanks; will do.  Are other commands also limited?  Are these limitation documented somewhere?

Comment: For what it's worth, here is the feature request: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=741000